# Coding and debugging JavaScript code only with a browser

Tags: javascript, debugging, console

[I'm new to JS, so I hope this is not a very silly question:]

I want to achieve the following:

1. Create an `.html` (with a `script` tag) and an empty `.js` file;
2. Use Firefox's Firebug\Chrome's Inspect tools* - namely, the console and the debugging tools;
3. Use these tools to write JS code snippets for learning purposes, and be able to debug them - but without the need to edit the `.js` file each time I have an error and then refresh the page etc, i.e., I want to do it all in the browser (and I guess it means it would be done with the console tool).

* I don't mind using any other tool; I just want to do everything in the browser, and if it is possible to skip step 1 - the better.

Comment: Have you tried [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: You can't easily do all that in every browser

Comment: jsfiddle sounds like a great option to me as well :)

Comment: yes, jsfiddle is a great option. but if you're offline then you can use firebug plugin for firefox. just right click on the page and select 'inspect element with firebug' then you can type the javascript code in the console tab.

Comment: Snipplets https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/snippets, but I think using a simple free editor is better than the console.

Answer (score 0):

## eval

A really basic method of debugging javascript directly in the browser is to write it into a text area and evaluate it. Note that `eval` in javascript returns the value of the last expression in its input string, or undefined if the last item in the string is a variable declaration, or nothing if an error occurs.

I'll include this example as a *starter*, but it's *student-ware* and far from unique! You can add buttons as you need them, say to fill the text area with a HTML template and another to write (edited) text to a popup window or new tab :D

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Eval</title><meta charset="utf-8">

<script>
function clearAreas(){
   document.getElementById("source").value = "";
   document.getElementById("result").value = "";
}
function evalSource() {
   document.getElementById("result").value =
   eval( document.getElementById("source").value);
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color: #778899;">
<button type="button" onclick="clearAreas();">clear</button>
<button type="button" onclick="evalSource()">=</button><br>
<textarea cols="80" rows="20" id="source">type script here</textarea><br>
<textarea cols="80" rows="5" id="result">eval result appears here</textarea>

</body></html>
```

Test

```
let add = ( a, b) => a+b;
add( 123, 456)
```

Type the code into the top text area and click equals. Now open the console, create a syntax error in the code and click equals again. Check line numbers used in console error messages correspond to lines within the text area.

Comment: To be honest, I haven't learned about eval yet, so I still can't fully understand what your'e doing here (Though I did what you suggested and I indeed can see the error lines). Anyway, I do want something more than that, and it is just a stater.